# Robotium ---> Instead of webview button, it clicks on edittext box

Tags: android, android-webview, robotium

I'm pretty new with Appium. I tried **robotium blackbox way** with **.apk** file to fill up a small web-view form which is auto injected by other rails server and every thing is working fine for me but

When i tried to click on **Save & Next** button it clicks on the edit-text box in which my previous entry filed through script.

I used all the way

```
solo.waitForText("SaveAndNext");
solo.clickOnWebElement(By.id("SaveAndNext"));
solo.clickOnWebElement(By.name("Save & Next"));
solo.clickOnWebElement(By.textContent("Save & Next"));
```

**But it click on the edittext box.**

**Here is my code :-**

solo.waitForActivity("ViewQuestions");

```
getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
solo.clickOnText("(?i).*?Yes.*");

solo.enterTextInWebElement(By.className("text_answer"), "2");
solo.hideSoftKeyboard();

solo.waitForText("SaveAndNext");
//solo.clickOnWebElement(By.id("SaveAndNext"));
//solo.clickOnWebElement(By.name("Save & Next"));
//solo.clickOnWebElement(By.textContent("Save & Next"));

for (WebElement webElement : solo.getCurrentWebElements()) {
  Log.d("Robotium", "id: " + webElement.getId() + " textContent: "
      + webElement.getTagName());
  if (webElement.getId() == "SaveAndNext") {
    solo.clickOnWebElement(By.id("SaveAndNext"));
  }
}
```

I have checked that **if (webElement.getId() == "SaveAndNext")** is found passed.
And in logcat

```
**Robotium id: SaveAndNext textContent: INPUT**
```

is shown.

[image]

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this for loop and use just:

```
solo.clickOnWebElement(By.id("SaveAndNext"));
```

Btw you cannot compare Strings like:

```
webElement.getId() == "SaveAndNext"
```

You should rather use equals:

```
"SaveAndNext".equals(webElement.getId())
```

Comment: Yes. this all stuff I have mentioned in my given code
solo.clickOnWebElement(By.id("SaveAndNext"));
solo.clickOnWebElement(By.name("Save & Next"));
solo.clickOnWebElement(By.textContent("Save & Next"));

Thanks for string comparison

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with view clicks were not proper. Got this solution from robotium.org

**Why do text and button clicks get wrong?**

If this problem happens on one of the supported versions then try to add this tag to the test project's AndroidManifest.xml

uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="YOUR_VERSION"

Where YOUR_VERSION is 6 for Android 2.0, 7 for Android 2.1 and 8 for Android 2.2.

If that does not solve the problem then try to add this tag to the AndroidManifest.xml of the application you want to test:

supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"

Comment: thanks. This is something that i dint know but it is not working for me yet, even though I have changed the devices.

I'm working with Robotium developer Renas and they are also able to reproduce this issue. I hope they will come up with some solution.

Comment: did you try to add this tag to the AndroidManifest.xml:                supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"

Comment: Still not working. FYI This HTML form is dynamically injected by Rails server.